# What is the Average instruction Execution time?

Tags: memory, operating-system, paging, cpu-architecture, tlb

This is my homework question. I just want to confirm my approach and hence the answer.

**A computer system with 2 level paging scheme in which regular memory access takes 300 nanoseconds and servicing a pagefault takes 500ns. An average instruction takes 200 ns of CPU time and one memory access. The TLB hit ratio is 80% and page fault ratio is 20%. The average instruction execution time is ?**

My Approach =>

```
**Average time To Execute Instruction = CPU Time + Memory Access Time**

It is given that CPU Time = 200 ns 
Probability of having a page fault for an instruction = 20% = 1/5  
Hence, probability of not having a page fault = 4/5

If TLB hit occurs, 
then memory Access time = 0 + 300 = 300 ns ( Here, TLB is taken negligible, so,  0 )

and


if TLB miss occurs,
then Memory Access Time = TLB access time + Access time Page Table 1 +
Access time Page table 2 + one memory Access = 0+ 300 + 300 + 300 =  900 ns
( Assume  all  the  page  tables  in  main  memory )

Hit ratio of TLB = 80 %

Hence, Memory Access Time = prob. of no page fault (...Memory 
access...........) + prob. of page fault (.......Page fault service 
time..........)

Memory Access Time = 4/5 ( 0.80 * 300 + 0.20 * 900 )
+ 1/5 ( (0.80 * 300 + 0.20 * 900) + 500 ns for servicing a page fault ) 
                                 = 336 + 184  
                                 = 520 ns 

Average time To Execute Instruction = CPU Time + Memory Access Time 
Average time To Execute Instruction = 200 ns + 520 ns = 720 ns .
```

Please correct me, if i am doing any mistake.

Comment: I can't believe any school was ask questions this moronic.

Comment: @user3344003, What is so moronic about it ?

Comment: It has no relation to reality. There is no average instruction time. Different instructions have different times to execute. The average time depends upon the mix of instructions that in turn depends upon the task at hand. There are so many variables that they have distilled down to 4.

Comment: @user3344003, Take it as a generalized question. Dont take it to deep. What do u think about the solution

Comment: @user3344003: a [classic RISC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classic_RISC_pipeline) has mostly uniform instruction execution times, unlike x86, esp. in a really simple design without a cache.  Intro to computer architecture questions like this use over-simplified models just so they can ask questions that have a specific answer to see if the student understands the meaning of the question and can plug in the numbers, not because it's supposed to be a realistic model of anything that might come up in perf analysis for real code on any modern CPU.

Comment: You're describing busy work; not learning about computer systems.